# How to use JavaScript to get the content in <s:textfield/>?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I use Struts2 tag to make a form. How to use JavaScript to get the content in the form?

code:`<s:textfield id="loginName" name="loginName" theme="simple"/>`

...

document.getElementById("loginName").getAttribute("value");//not work
document.getElementById("loginName").innerText;//not work too

Comment: document.getElementById("loginName").value is what you need

Comment: in your code you haven't assign a value to your textfield, if you test it like <s:textfield id="loginName" name="loginName" theme="simple">Testing</s:textfield> , document.getElementById("loginName").innerText; will work

Comment: s.textfield is not a standard HTML tag. That means JSP will render it as a normal <input type="text" /> tag. So, simply use what @PaulZepernick and Pluda said.

Comment: I get it. Thanks all of you.